# How to add a drawer to SilverAppBar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have used SilverAppBar but don't know how to add a drawer to it. I just want an app bar with a drawer that hides on scrolling

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `Scaffold` takes care of all of the major behavior associated with Material design.

If you add the `drawer` field to your `Scaffold`, it will automatically add a hamburger menu icon to the left hand side of your `SilverAppBar` in flutter.

Code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
        title: Text('Drawer - Sliver AppBar'),
      )],
    ),
    drawer: Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text(' I am Drawer'),
            curve: SawTooth(12),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I i use this then when i am going down the appbar is also hidden what i dont want.
and If i am using AppBar() then the drawing is setting two different drawer button!